# Mongo query optimisation in Redash Tool

Tags: mongodb, merge, collections, aggregation, redash

```
{
  "collection": "dispatchrequests",
  "aggregate": [
    {
      "$match": {
        "source_city_name": "{{Source}}",
        "destination_city_name": "{{destination}}",
        "start_date": {
          "$gte": "{{doj-start}}",
          "$lte": "{{doj-end}}"
        },
        "booking_status": "TRAVELLED"
      }
    },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": {
          "source_city_name": "$source_city_name",
          "destination_city_name": "$destination_city_name",
          "start_date": "$start_date"
        },
        "count_dispatchrequests": {
          "$sum": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "source_city_name": "$_id.source_city_name",
        "destination_city_name": "$_id.destination_city_name",
        "start_date": "$_id.start_date",
        "count_dispatchrequests": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "competitivepricings",
        "let": {
          "source": "$source_city_name",
          "destination": "$destination_city_name",
          "date": "$start_date"
        },
        "pipeline": [
          {
            "$match": {
              "$expr": {
                "$and": [
                  { "$eq": ["$source_city_name", "$$source"] },
                  { "$eq": ["$destination_city_name", "$$destination"] },
                  { "$eq": ["$start_date", "$$date"] },
                  { "$eq": ["$funnel_type", "NORMAL"] }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "as": "competitive_data"
      }
    },
    {
      "$unwind": {
        "path": "$competitive_data",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
      }
    },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": "$start_date",
        "count_competitivepricings": {
          "$sum": 1
        },
        "count_dispatchrequests": {
          "$first": "$count_dispatchrequests"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "source_city_name": "$_id.source_city_name",
        "destination_city_name": "$_id.destination_city_name",
        "start_date": "$_id",
        "count_competitivepricings": 1,
        "count_dispatchrequests": 1,
        "conversionRatio": {
          "$cond": [
            { "$eq": ["$count_competitivepricings", null] },
            null,
            { "$divide": ["$count_competitivepricings", "$count_dispatchrequests"] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

One of the indexes in the database is `source_city_name_destination_city_name_updatedAt`. Can this be integrated in order to optimise this query as it is taking too long to run or is there any other method to optimise this?

This operation is designed to get the ratio of `count_competitivepricings` and `count_dispatchrequests` using two collections `dispatchrequests` and `competitivepricings`.